# show carrier name on status bar (galaxy A5 2016)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have a Samsung galaxy A5 2016, and I would like to know if somebody knows how to activate to show the carrier name in the status bar.
I have searched in the entire menu (settings) but I cannot find this option.

I would appreciate your help!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do the same to my devices, and after extensive searching it looks like the only way out is to root and modify the SystemUI yourself. Refer [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2401367) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2440995) for steps on how to do this. This still works as of Android 6.0.

This will be even harder to do on Samsung phones, because their framework is tightly integrated and you might not even be able to decompile the framework in the first place.